# Colocar todos os itens dentro de uma pasta no realtime database firebase

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebase, inserir

Estou tentando pegar todos os itens do database e colocar dentro de uma pasta. Quando fui mexer no banco de dados esqueci de colocar o diretório para os itens irem para uma pasta
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muitas tentativas e erros achei um "jeito", talvez exista um meio mais prático e fácil, enfim, o que tive que fazer foi o seguinte:

1 - Tá ligado no seu realtime Database? Então, quando você entrar nele, verá que tem os três pontinhos, ao lado de um '+' e '-'. Aperte nele e exporte o JSON.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Blz, agora que você exportou faça o seguinte:

Abra o VsCode ou algum editor de texto de sua preferência.

O arquivo JSON, de forma bruta, é basicamente uma hierarquia de dados, para colocar os dados dentro de uma pasta onde não existia vamos criar uma:

No meu caso, eu queria colocar todos os dados dentro de uma pasta chamada 'produtos', então logo no início coloque a palavra 'produtos: {}', dentro dessas chaves é onde vc vai colocar os itens do seu banco de dados.

(Tendi foi é nada). Ok, vou deixar uma imagem pra faciliar :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra finalizar salve o seu arquivo e importe lá no realtime database nos mesmos 3 pontinhos :))))